# Which Is Correct: exact date or exact dates?

Tags: grammatical-number

Is it correct to make the word "date" plural or leave it singular in phrase below:

> Enter the exact date you started and finished each employment.

or

> Enter the exact dates you started and finished each employment.

Comment: Both are understood and I think both are grammatical. I prefer *dates*.

Comment: Not what you asked about, but "...each employment" sounds weird to me, I would say "...each job".

Comment: @nnnnnn it is possible to have multiple jobs within a single continuous employment.

Comment: @KillingTime - Possible to have multiple jobs while working for the same employer, sure, but using the word "employment" like that still sounds weird and I would rephrase to avoid it. (Also, when providing an employment history it would make sense to list different jobs with the same employer separately, to makes one's breadth of experience clearer.)

Comment: Both are understood; I prefer *date,* because you don't have more than one start date or finish date for each entry. However, as @MikeGraham indicates, this is merely a preference.

Comment: Just use “*dates(s)*”that way there is no obligation for it to be singular or plural. This is what is usually done when there is ambiguity. But both are acceptable as people have said.

Comment: @nnnnnn - How do you feel about “... each term of employment”?

Comment: @Jim I'm going to change employment to job. It sounds and reads easier. This text is for a web page form and I want to make the instructions to enter this information as easy as possible for the user w/o any ambiguity.

Comment: @nnnnnn "An employment" (count noun) is perfectly normal everyday English - OED sense 5c of the noun "employment". *c. A (usually paid) position of regular work; an office, a post; a situation.* Its earliest example is from 1590, and the most recent shown is from 2007 - *2007   P. C. Tulsian Bus. & Industr. Law vi. v   X promises to pay Y Rs 50,000 if Y secures him an employment in Govt. service.* Merriam Webster records exactly the same sense at ref 2b of the noun. It seems to me it is alive and well on both sides of the Atlantic.

Comment: @WS2. Fair enough. Perhaps it sounds weird to me because in my experience people don't normally use the word that way here in Australia. (Perhaps if you look you'll find some examples, but it's certainly not common.) That usage would be understood though, of course.